Embed the Salesforce Customer Community Experience into an iFrame on a different site and pass SAML credentials
I am currently implementing a Gainsight Customer Community.
The Gainsight community is using Salesforce SAML as our identity provider.
We would like to iframe in our Salesforce support portal so that our users in Gainsight can submit cases to Salesforce.  Ideally, this would pass the login credentials to the iframe so that the users have a seamless experience and don't have to log in multiple times.
I have the login working to Gainsight.  I have the Salesforce Support Portal iframed in and loading.  I cannot figure out if it is possible to automatically pass the credentials and login.
